# why can't i read any video with openCV 3 and python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I am coding OpenCV with Python. I can't figure out how to read a video with `cv2.VideoCapture()`.

It is working fine with my webcam but doesn't return anything not even any error messages when I run the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For what I did to solve this was:

1.used 
`cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\vtest.avi")` (nothing happened)

2.copied 
The `opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll` to the `base location(C:\Python27)` even in
the folder called `DLLs(C:\Python27\DLLs)` but nothing is working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your code didn't find that video. Either make sure your video is in the same directory as your source code or give it an absolute path.

For working with paths, its better to use a dedicated module which can handle path modifications for you, like https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html.